# The Euler-Lagrange equation associated with $L(p,z,x)=\frac{1}{2}(|p|^2+f(x)z)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I'm studying the calculus of variations by referring to the PDE book by Lawrence C. Evans (chapter 8, 2nd edition). After learning the Euler-Lagrange equation
$$-\sum_{i=1}^n(L_{p_i}(Du,u,x))_{x_i}+L_z(Du,u,x)=0$$
associated with the energy functional
$$I[w]=\int L(Dw(x),w(x),x),$$
I got myself an exercise from some other book, which is to minimize the functional
$$A(v)=\int\frac{1}{2}(|\nabla v|^2+fv).\tag{$*$}$$
I don't bother about the minimizing stuff; all I want to do is find the correct form of its Euler-Lagrange equation. And for some reasons, the author **implicitly** suggests that the Euler-Lagrange equation is the Poisson equation
$$\Delta v=f,\tag{$**$}$$
which begs a question: **is there any typo in $(*)$?** Based on what I just learned, we have
$$L(p,z,x)=\frac{1}{2}(|p|^2+f(x)z)$$
if $(*)$ is to be considered. Then some calculus gives us
$$\Delta v=\frac{1}{2}f,$$
a result differing from the expectation $(**)$ by a factor $1/2$. So my guess would be that something is wrong with the functional $A$. **Should we have instead
$$A(v)=\int(\frac{1}{2}|\nabla v|^2+fv)?$$**
I was trying to contact the author, but it didn't do much good. Much is appreciated if someone could give me some confidence. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yep, you are correct.

Comment: @CheeHan Thank you.